# Java - for и getText();

Tags: java, swing

Хочу отправить данные с лейблов и комбобоксов, как это сделать?

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            String iString = Integer.toString(i);
            JLabel Name = new JLabel("ingridient" + iString);
            String N = Name.getText();
            JTextField Data = new JTextField("Data_Ingridient" + iString);
            String D = Data.getText();
            WR.Write(N, D);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Чего вы ожидаете, вызывая метод `getText` только что созданного `JTextField`?

Comment: У меня есть 7 элементов ingridient и Data_Ingridient. Мне нужно перебрать каждый и забрать с них данные, передав их в функцию.

Comment: В приведённом вами коде вы 7 раз создаёте новых пустой элемент, даже не привязанных к форме окна и прекращающий существование уже в конце итерации.

Comment: Натолкните пожалуйста на пусть истинный, как с существующих 7 объектов забрать текст и передать в функцию?

Comment: При создании окна сохранять его компоненты в поля класса или список, а в обработчике обращаться к полям или итерировать по списку. Можно и динамически получить список компонентов формы с помощью [Container.getComponents()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents--), но это костыль.

Comment: А как можно именно функцией забрать и передать значения в другую? Могли бы ли вы, пожалуйста показать пример